# EF 7 - Navigation properties - incorrect SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Does EF7 fully support navigation properties and custom projection? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding how to construct this query. The `Study` entity has a nullable `ProjectId` and corresponding virtual `Project` navigation property. The `Project` entity has a non-nullable `CategoryId` and `Category` navigation property. The entities were reverse scaffolded using the `ef` command.

If I run the following query:

```
return _context.Study
            .Include(s => s.Project)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
            .Select(s => new Models.StudySearchResult
            {
                StudyId = s.StudyId,
                MasterStudyId = s.MasterStudyId,
                ShortTitle = s.ShortTitle,
                Category = s.Project == null ? string.Empty : s.Project.Category.CategoryDesc,
                SubmitterId = s.SubmitterId
            }).ToList();
```

EF7 incorrectly generates the following SQL, which uses `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT [s].[StudyId]
    ,[s].[MasterStudyId]
    ,[s].[ShortTitle]
    ,CASE WHEN [s].[ProjectId] IS NULL THEN @__Empty_0 ELSE [s.Project.Category].[CategoryDesc] END
    ,[s].[SubmitterId]
FROM [Study] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [Project] AS [s.Project]
    ON [s].[ProjectId] = [s.Project].[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [s.Project.Category]
    ON [s.Project].[CategoryId] = [s.Project.Category].[CategoryId]
```

Comment: Does ProjectId member has `[Required]` attribute in the model?

Comment: No, the Study model (generated from scaffolding) does not have required attribute for `ProjectId`. I did check `OnModelCreating()` for the DbContext and found the following configuration: `entity.HasOne(d => d.Project).WithMany(p => p.Study).HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId);` is configured for Study, which seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. And I found out that there is currently open issue in EF7 for generating SQL for optional navigations. It will be fixed in RC2.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4205 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3186